# Как убрать пробелы до точки?

Tags: python

```
word_list = ["My", "name", "is", "Sergei", "EOS", "I'm", "from", "Moscow", "EOS"]
N=len(word_list)
for i in range(N):
        if word_list[i]=="EOS":
            word_list[i]='.'
            c=' '.join(word_list)                    
print(c)
```

Пытаюсь вывести

> My name is Sergei. I'm from Moscow.

А выходит

> My name is Sergei . I'm from Moscow .

Comment: Вам пытались помочь три чеоловека. Затратили время. Если вам несложно  -  отметьте какой то из ответов как решение зелененькой галочкой.  Или прокоментируйте  -  что в предложенных вариантах вам не понравилось.  Карма она есть. Сегодня православная Пасха. Так вот. Что посеет человек, то и пожнет - написанов Новом Завете

Answer (score 1):

```
word_list = ["My", "name", "is", "Sergei", "EOS", "I'm", "from", "Moscow", "EOS"]

for i in range(len(word_list)):
    if word_list[i]=="EOS":
        word_list[i]='.'
        result = ' '.join(word_list)
                
print(result.replace(" .", ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word_list = ["My", "name", "is", "Sergei", "EOS", "I'm", "from", "Moscow", "EOS"]
sentence=[]
result=''
for word in word_list:
        if word!="EOS":
            sentence.append(word)
        else:
            result+=' '.join(sentence)+'.'
            sentence = ['']
print(result)
```

Вывод:

> My name is Sergei. I'm from Moscow.

Answer (score -1):

```
word_list = ["My", "name", "is", "Sergei", "EOS", "I'm", "from", "Moscow", "EOS"]
c = ' '.join(word_list).replace(' EOS', '.')
print(c)


"My name is Sergei. I'm from Moscow."
```

**Дополнительно.**
Не знаю, за что поставили минус моему ответу. Наверное это лабараторка была и по ее условиям надо `EOS` по условиям заменить на точку,  а потому убрать лишний пробел. Ну так вот - пользуйтесь.

```
word_list = ["My", "name", "is", "Sergei", "EOS", "I'm", "from", "Moscow", "EOS"]
c = ' '.join(word_list).replace('EOS', '.').replace(' .', '.')
print(c)

My name is Sergei. I'm from Moscow.
```